# Android Studio 2.2.3 - aidl is missing - I Can't Downgrade my SDK Build Tools

Tags: android, android-studio

Running Android Studio 2.2.3, if I attempt to run a program I am told my aidl is missing. I have read through the other questions but I am only seeing posts from 2015.

I attempt to follow the instructions and downgrade my "Compile Sdk Version" and then downgrade my "Build Tools Version." However, I am not given any other comile sdk version options other than 7.1.1 Nougat. Build tools versions only offers me 25.0.1 or 25.0.2.

The error code is below. I am new to this, I know a some Java and just wanted to explore a bit. I've search for an hour and a half how to solve this. Maybe I am just dumb. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing
```

Comment: what build tools version are you using? what is the content of `<sdk>/build-tools/<VERSION>`?

Answer (score 1):

try to run "Emulator" and choose Android 7.x (last version) is running.
And then try to debug on my "USB Device", the problem solved.